# DISCORD.JS: Message.awaitReactions not firing

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

When I run this code sendReact() executes but nothing else—no errors. The .catch() function is the only thing that executes after 5 seconds. When I react to my embed that I created with sendReact(), nothing happens. This happens in my command file as well as my index.js file if I moved the code there. Nothing is being logged to the console.

```
  var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // 1-rock 2-paper 3-scissors
  let playerPick = 0;

  sendReact() // sends the embed message with the reactions

  message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == '✂️'),
  { max: 1, time: 5000 }).then(collected => {

    if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
      console.log('rock');
      playerPick = 1;
    } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
      console.log('paper');
      playerPick = 2;
    } else if (collected.first().emoji.name == '✂️') {
      console.log('scissors');
      playerPick = 3;
    }

    console.log("Player pick: " + playerPick);
    console.log("CPU pick: " + pick);

  }).catch(() => {
    message.reply('No reaction after (how many) seconds, game cancelled.');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to this is because you're awaiting reactions on your own `message`.

You need to make `awaitReactions()` listen to reactions on the embed you're sending.

```js
const msg = await sendReact()
msg.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == '✂️'),
  { max: 1, time: 5000 }).then(collected => { })
```

Comment: Also, for me to do that, I need sendReact() to return something right? I just let it return the embed itself and it seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating an embed with `sendReact()`, but then you call `message.awaitReactions(...)`. Which message is that referring to? Most likely you're waiting for reactions on the message that triggered this command, instead of on the message with the embed you sent with `sendReact()`. The only way you can tell the bot to wait for reactions on the *new* message is to get a reference to it, and call `awaitReactions()` on that reference.

So, for example:

```
//in an async function...
let gameMessage = await sendReact();

gameMessage.awaitReactions(...).then(collected => {
  //handle reaction
});
```